# Power Mac G5 2005 boots with flashing question mark

Tags: macos, mac, g5

Upon start up there is continuous beeping and clicking resulting in a gray screen with a flashing screen ? icon.

I've reset PRAM and hit the reset button on the inside.  I've tried to start from another drive, but I am not sure I have a proper back up.  That resulted in a screen with a reset arrow and an arrow pointed to the right.

I have not tried to blow out dust yet, but I'm wondering if my start up drive is shot.  If so, will replacing it help? And what drive should I replace it with?

Upon running a diagnostics (when I could) this error resulted.

```
2STF /8/3: A upper
```

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the hard drive in the upper bay is failing.

- Failing hard drives often make loud clicking sounds.  It's not as common, but is far from uncommon to hear beep error tones from failing hard drives as well.
- The gray screen with an flashing folder icon occurs when the Mac cannot find a valid OS X system to boot to.  This can be a result of a badly corrupted operating system (often resulting from impending hard drive failure), a failed hard drive or a new unformatted hard drive.
- The AHT error code more than likely stands for SATA Function or something similar, and since it references "upper" I would interpret that as the upper of two items.  Depending on your G5 PowerMac you might have dual processors but these are usually referred to as A or B and would throw a CPU error rather than STF.  Since there are two drive bays, where the two SATA disks are aligned vertically, I would interpret the error as meaning the upper disk is having the problem.

  ---

To diagnose the issue you could try this...

- Power your Mac on while holding <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Apple + V if an older keyboard).
- Assuming the disk isn't completely failed this should boot the Mac in verbose mode, where you can read what is occurring as the Mac is attempting to boot.
- I would be on the lookout for "Disk I/O" errors, these will indicate a hardware failure with the hard drive itself.  If the Mac doesn't boot to verbose mode and instead only shows the flashing folder icon again then I would again assume a hardware failure.  With AHT (the diagnostic you ran) already reporting an error this is likely the scenario.

---

More than likely replacing the startup disk WILL fix the issue.  Most any 3.5" SATA disk will work although I would keep it relatively small (less than 250GB) as some of the earlier PowerMac G5s had firmware limitations on hard drive capacity.  You will need to partition/format the disk using "Apple Partition Map" and re-install Mac OS X.

Hope that helps!